# require(events) === events.EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, node.js

Every example I see and the [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter) demonstrates after requiring the events module you should also call the property `.eventsEmitter`.  I don't see the difference between the two values, example (running in node):

```
var events = require('events');

console.log(events === events.EventEmitter);  // logs true;
console.log(new events()); // { domain: null, _events: {}, _maxListeners: undefined }
console.log(new events.EventEmitter()); // { domain: null, _events: {}, _maxListeners: undefined }
```

Is it necessary to call .EventEmitter? Why is it suggested?

Comment: Do you mean `require("events")` so you're passing a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing it with `.EventEmitter` was required in Node 0.10.x. If `console.log(events === events.EventEmitter);` is logging `true`, then you must be running Node 0.12.x or io.js. (I just tested and it logs `false` in 0.10.36 but `true` in 0.12.2 and io.js 2.0.2.

So you should be sure to use `.EventEmitter` if there is a chance you or someone else will need your code to work in Node 0.10.x.

Comment: Here's the proof in the source: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L32; you beat me to the answer.